# Is there a way to renew the certificates without having to change (the thumprints of) the certificates in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: sql, powershell, certificate

I am adding/changing certificates to SQL (both manually and through powershell scripting).

I find the certificate-> add it to SQL (either manually in the configuration manager or through powershell -> placing the thumbprint of the certificate in the SQL-registry).
This all seems to be working fine.
BUT when I renew the certificate (right click certificate-> All Tasks->"Renew Certificate with New Key..."), due to expiration of this certificate or other reasons), the old thumbprint will remain in the SQL-registry and the SQL Configuration manager will show an empty line where the certificate was.

Is there a way to renew the certificates without having to change (the thumprints of) the certificates in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this.

The Thumbprint is a hash of a number of the properties in a cert. If even one property were minutely different, it would result in a dramatically different certificate hash.

> A(...) thumbprint is a computed field, i.e. not a part of the certificate data itself. In the GUI these are called Properties. In the shell extension the thumbprint is called thumbprint and in the Certutil output it is called Cert hash. From this we can surmise that the thumbprint is some kind of hash or one way function (OWF), whose friendly name is thumbprint.

This [post goes into greater details.](https://morgansimonsen.com/2013/04/16/understanding-x-509-digital-certificate-thumbprints/)

After you update a cert, you could just run a tSql script to update the cert binding on the SQL Servers.  [This post goes into good details about what that would look like.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5009/updating-an-expired-sql-server-tde-certificate/)

You could then run the script using PowerShell's SQL dbaTools module.

Comment: Thanks!

I was hoping, that the operating system or SQL would automatically pick up the change of the certificate (since it's just a renewal of an existing certificate), but I seem to have to do something in SQL every time a certificate is renewed. Not ideal, but at least I know how to automate this... And I will make sure to put some alerting on the enddates of my certificates.

Comment: If you've got alerting when your certs expire and also auto updating your certs, you're doing better than 80% of shops out there!

Comment: Sorry to come back to this, but I found out that the machinekey (C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys), that was created during the rrenewal of the certificate, seems to have "inherited" the ACL-properties from the machine key, that belonged to the previous certificate.
And it seems that I can still log onto this specific machine with the "encryption option" on in SSMS.
This could mean, that I do not have to modify the certificate in the SQL Server configuration or the registry, after a renewal of the certificate...
Does this make any sense?